Algorithm for Minimizing Bandwidth in Non-Square Matrices
Cuthill-McKee algorithm is used to minimize the bandwidth of square matrices by positioning non-zero values closer to the diagonal.
I am wondering if there exists a similar algorithm that can be applied to non-square matrices.
Specifically, I am looking for a method to rearrange the matrix so that non-zero elements are as tightly clustered as possible. Non-square matrices don't have a diagonal line, but maybe we can still use the term bandwidth.
The goal is to maximize the number of full-zero blocks when the matrix is divided into sub-blocks.
Any suggestions or references to relevant algorithms would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Here's an example: the following is a 4x6 matrix, and I can divide the matrix into 2x2 blocks. (In practice I am doing this for large matrices and block_size << matrix_size, so block size does not matter)
[
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
]

Now, only the top-right block is fully zero.
If I rearrange the rows:
row 1 as row 3
row 2 as row 1
row 3 as row 4
row 4 as row 2

The matrix becomes:
[
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
]

Then 3 blocks are fully zero: top-center, top-right, bottom-left

An example Input, wanted Output would be nice. Also "tightly clustered as possible" needs a formal definition to rank different transformed matrices.
